# Comparing chars always outputs false, even when it should be true

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm completely new to coding and i'm trying to make a simple game launcher. The idea is like this:

```
1    "Game 1"
2    "Game 2"
```

Where you have to enter the number to open the game.

but whenever i input something it always outputs false even if the input should be true. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    char test[100];
    cin >> test;
    cout << test;
    if (test=="1") {
        cout << "Correct!";
    }
    else cout << "Incorrect!";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By checking test=="1", you are actually comparing 2 addresses rather than the content of the arrays.

Comment: What will be the input ?. Will it simply be "1" and "2". In that case I would suggest to instead use int or short to save variables